# How to create a box which appears upon clicking menu item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have webpage which can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/saTfR/51/

How can I create a box which appears on the page when a user clicks "Portfolio"? I will also be adding PNG images inside this box. The user will click on an image and it will become bigger. Each image (once clicked) will have left and right arrows where the user can navigate the images.

HTML:

```
 <p class="text">text</p>        
<img id="map" src="http://www.local-guru.net/img/guru/worldglow.png" alt="map"/>
<p class="text">text</p>      


<div class="logo">
    <img id="logo" src="logo2.png" alt="Logo"> 
</div>
</html>

<ul id="menu">

        <li><a href=#ABOUT>About me</a></li>
        <li><a href=#PORTFOLIO>Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href=#CONTACT>Contact me</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
* {font-family: Lucida Console; }

.text{
    color:white;
    z-index:999;
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 5px;
    left:30%;
    font-size:25px;}

#menu{
color:white;
position: fixed;
top:50%;
left:3px;
}

#logo {
    position: fixed; 
    right: 2px; 
    top: 5px; 
    z-index: 10;
}

#map {
   background-attachment: fixed;}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".text").hide().fadeIn(2000);
var mywindow = $(window);
var pos = mywindow.scrollTop();
mywindow.scroll(function() {
    if(mywindow.scrollTop() > pos)
    {
        $('.text').fadeOut();  
    }
    else
    {
        $('.text').fadeIn();
    }
    pos = mywindow.scrollTop();
 });
```

Comment: is there something about Lightbox that doesn't meet your needs? http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
There is many different ways to do this but I think the most popular would be either using JavaScript or jQuery.

//Have an element (the box) you want to show
<div id="portfolio_box"></div>

//The CSS for the box (make sure you have the display set to none)
<style>
    #portfolio_box{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: white;

        display: none;
    }
</style>

//Call the function
<li><a href="#PORTFOLIO" onclick="portfolio();">About me</a></li>


//The function in JavaScript
<script type="text/javascript">

    function portfolio(){
        document.getElementById("portfolio").style.display = "block";
    }

</script>

// Or jQuery (if it's jquery you want to have the element you want clicked to have a class or ID)

//The class/id

 <li><a href=#PORTFOLIO class="b_portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>

//jQuery
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.b_portfolio').on('click', function(){
            $('#portfolio_box').css({display: 'block'});
        })
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Also if you want to make the images bigger, you can use css (through JavaScript or Jquery) but the arrow buttons are a bit harder. If you don't want to put the work it to do it I would advise using a jQuery image slider plugin

Comment: the code does not seem to show a box when I click on "Portfolio". Not sure if I did something else wrong. I tried it several times

Comment: I just coded up and example for you. http://puu.sh/jm5SA/1107155936.txt
It might make things more clear

Comment: I understand it better. Thanks

Comment: Your welcome! You can help others by clicking the 'tick' on my answer so others can know the answer too.